# SVN Incremental Backup

Tags: svn, visualsvn-server

A full backup of our SVN repo is ~3GB.
Naturally, I'd like to perform incremental backups.

My question is as follows and please bear with me as I'm not very familiar with version control:

Today's Full backup contains 315 revisions.
If tomorrow someone performs a change of some kind, would that neccesarily count as revision 316+ ? If not how am I to backup that specific change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
svnadmin dump --incremental -rlast_backedUp+1:HEAD <PATH to repo>
```

You can also backup the current commit in a post-commit hookscript which is even easier and more flexible, as you have each commit separately.

Comment: I figured the syntax, i just wanted to know if each revision counts as a change.

Comment: Yes, if you mean change is a commit, each commit creates a new revision. Note that in SVN a comit can span multiple file-changes.

Answer (score 0):

The answer in short is YES.
Each revision accounts for a change in the SVN from what I read and heard.
The syntax is per Peter's post.